# python sqlite check points?

Tags: python, sqlite, rollback

I working with python sqlite3 , I found we have commit and rollback option.
Does sqlite3 allows something like check point ?

For example: Initial state is empty.
...
insert something 
...
commit 
....
.....
insert something 
commit.
update something
Found some problem.Now I want to roll back to initial state. Something like multiple undo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I don't know of any SQL database engine supporting "multiple undo" -- if one exists at all, Sqlite is definitely not it!  For *nested* transactions (a less general concept), consider (per [Sqlite's docs](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_transaction.html)!) the `SAVEPOINT` feature -- it may be sufficient to do most of what you require.